# Importação de arquivo Excel para o R

Tags: r, data.frame

Estou tendo problema com a importação de um arquivo em excel para o R. Estou utilizando o pacote readxl, meu diretório de trabalho está definido no mesmo local que o arquivo excel :

```
setwd("C:/R sidra")
```

Porém, ao executar o comando do readxl, não encontra o caminho do arquivo:

```
library(read_excel)

read_excel("MUNICÍPIOS")
```

> Error: `path` does not exist: ‘MUNICÍPIOS’

Answer (score 2):

Se o seu problema é a especificação do caminho, tente trazê-lo com a seguinte função:

```
file.choose()
```

Ela abrirá o menu de pastas do seu sistema operacional. Dê dois cliques sobre o **arquivo** que deseja importar. O caminho deste arquivo será emitido ao Console do R. Algo assim:

```
"/home/user/importR/my1/MeusDados.xlsx"
```

Copie este caminho (`"/home/user/importR/my1/MeusDados.xlsx"`) *sem* o nome do arquivo. Desta forma:

```
"/home/user/importR/my1"
```

Utilize-o na função abaixo. Assim:

```
setwd("/home/user/importR/my1")
```

Tente realizar a importação com o nome *completo* do arquivo (`"/home/user/importR/my1/MeusDados.xlsx"`):

```
library(readxl)

meus_dados <- read_excel("/home/user/importR/my1/MeusDados.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá! Percebi que você não colocou o formato do arquivo ao final.

Vamos supor que seja .xlsx. Tente assim e veja se funciona:

```
library(readxl)

read_excel("MUNICÍPIOS.xlsx")
```

Comment: alterei o comando , porém o erro permanece   > read_excel("MUNICÍPIOS.xlxs")
Error: `path` does not exist: ‘MUNICÍPIOS.xlxs’

Comment: @IngledSeiévini, tente declarar todo o diretório. Exemplo: df <- read_excel("c:/sua/pasta/seu_arquivo.xlsx")

Comment: outra coisa, você escreveu no comentário  read_excel("MUNICÍPIOS.xlxs"). o correto é xlsx e não xlxs

Comment: Não tinha me atentado ao erro, mas corrigi e o erro persiste > read_excel("C:/R sidra/MUNICIPIOS.xlsx")
Error: `path` does not exist: ‘C:/R sidra/MUNICIPIOS.xlsx’

Comment: Ok. A mensagem de erro diz que o caminho não existe. O diretório está correto mesmo?
Copie e cole o arquivo, por exemplo, na pasta "c:/arquivo.xlsx" e tente novamente assim read_excel("c:/arquivo.xlsx")

Comment: outra coisa: o R as vezes não reconhece esse barra... tente read_excel("c//arquivo.xlsx") ou read_excel("c\arquivo.xlsx"). Verifique também se o formato do arquivo que você está querendo importar é o mesmo. (verifique clicando com o botão direito em cima do arquivo e depois em propriedades)

Comment: O arquivo está salvo em xls, fiz um teste conforme você me falou read_excel("C:\MUNICIPIOS.xlsx"), o resultado > read_excel("C:\MUNICIPIOS.xlsx")
Error: '\M' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""C:\M"

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93188/discussion-between-lucca-ramalho-and-ingled-seievini).

Comment: Se o arquivo está salvo em XLS então você deve usar: df <- read_excel("c:/arquivo.xls"), caso contrário ele não será encontrado.

Answer (score 1):

O ideal é que você utilize um arquivo sem acentuação para evitar problemas de localização ou de encoding. Utilize no formato abaixo.

```
library(readxl)

read_excel("MUNICIPIOS.xlsx")
```

Lembre-se que o "xlsx" é o formato do arquivo, se o seu arquivo em Excel estiver como um CSV altere o formato no método acima.

Answer (score 0):

Se for um problema de encoding, tente achar o arquivo através de `pattern` em `dir()`. Coloquei um `pattern` bem geral mas você pode substituí-lo por algo mais específico.

```
file <- dir("C:/R sidra", pattern = "(?i)mun.*\\.xslx$", full.names = T)

dados <- readxl::read_xlsx(file)
```